# Running `Function Pointers` Within Running `POSIX` Thread in `C` `Thread Pool`

Tags: c, posix, threadpool

I'm creating a threadpool in `C` with pthreads, and while I have an idea of how it works, I have a few questions about the intricacies.

I've created a struct which is supposed to be my representation of a threadpool, containing a list of function pointers to run, we'll call it the work_list. The threadpool struct also holds mutex's(?) and conditions to syncronize access, an int for the number of threads and an array holding the thread id's of each worked thread.The work_list itself holds structs that represent functions to be completed, each instance of those structs holds a void* to a function, a void* for args and a void* to place results. When coded this idea fleshes out like this:

```
typedef struct threadpool
{
    list work_list;
    pthread_t* tidArray;
    int num_threads;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t condition;
} threadpool;
```

and:

```
typedef struct fuFunction
{
    void* functionCall;
    void* functionArgs;
    void* returnValue;
    list_elem elem;
} fuFunction;
```

I currently have a thread which initializes the a pool. It takes in a int num_of_threads, and returns a pointer to instance of a threadpool with all the members initialized. The body I've created looks like this:

```
threadpool * threadpool_init(int num_of_threads)
{
    threadpool* retPool = (threadpool*) malloc(sizeof(threadpool));

    //Initialize retPool members

    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < num_of_threads; x++)
    {
            pthread_t tid;

            if( pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_start, retPool) != 0)
            {
                    printf("Error creating worker thread\nExting\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            retPool->tidArray[x] = tid;
    }

    return retPool;
}
```

The function that each thread runs when started, the worker function, thread_star, looks like this so far:

```
void *thread_start(void* args)
{
    threadpool* argue = (threadpool*) args;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(argue->lock));
    while(\* threadpool not shut down*\)
    {
            if(!list_empty(&argue->work_list))
            {
                    fuFunction* tempFu = list_entry(list_pop_front(&argue->workQ), fuFunction, elem);

                    \\WHAT TO PUT HERE
            }

            pthread_cond_wait(&argue->condition, &argue->lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(argue->lock));
}
```

My question is, assuming this code I currently have is right, how would I get the worker threads to run the function in the tempFu that it makes in the worker function? Sorry if this is long or confusing, I find this much easier to explain in conversation. If this is FUBAR, let me know as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the struct element signiture "void* functionCall;" is wrong. 
use a function pointer instead.
Eg:

```
typedef struct fuFunction
{
    void* (*functionCall)( void* arg);
    void* functionArgs;
    void* returnValue;
    list_elem elem;
} fuFunction;
```

then put there:

```
tempfu->returnValue = (*tempfu->functionCall)(tempfu->functionArgs);
```